# Samsung Galaxy Tab P-1000 no longer recognised by the computer

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab

I have a [Samsung Galaxy Tab P-1000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Tab). I tried to add a language to it using some software, but it stopped working and now my computer can not recognize it. Signs of computer and mobile appear in the black screen only. What shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting your Galaxy Tab in Download mode.  This is done by completely shutting it off, and then holding both Power and Volume Down buttons together until a big yellow sign with a droid holding a shovel appears, with "Downloading, do not turn off target" message underneath.  If so, you can try flashing the stock ROM via Odin or Heimdal utilities.

You can find the detailed instructions on the Development section of [XDA-Developers forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=807).